# An urn has 5 blue, 3 green and 7 yellow marbles. two marbles are drawn without replacement. probability that the 3rd one will be a green marble?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Probability of 3rd ball being green while drawn without replacement, in a case where there are 5 blue 3 green and 7 yellow marbles in an urn. I'm having a hard time coming to a conclusion about the process of the math. I drew a probability tree to have a better understanding, the final branch being P(green) and P(green)', then I added the probabilities of the 3rd one being green and divided it by all possible outcomes of the third pick. My answer comes to 7/39 but I'm not sure if my process is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: What were the leaves of your tree diagram ? Did you at least reduce the compartmentalisation, by categorising the marbles as green and *not-green* ? If not, can you try that ? Although, when you come to the right answer, it may strike you that even that was not required.

Comment: I did the green and not green part, where I did wrong was that I didn't multiply the first two outcomes with the third; thinking it would be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Case I: First two marble is other than green marble and third is green marble.

Probability of case I $=  \frac{12}{15}\cdot \frac{11}{14} \cdot \frac{3}{13}=\frac{66}{455}$

> Case II: First marble is other than green marble and second and third is green marble.

Probability of case II $=  \frac{12}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14} \cdot \frac{2}{13}=\frac{12}{455}$

> Case III: All three is green marble.

Probability of case III $=  \frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{2}{14} \cdot \frac{1}{13}=\frac{1}{455}$

> Case IV: First and third is green marble.

Probability of case IV $=  \frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{12}{14} \cdot \frac{2}{13}=\frac{12}{455}$

Total Probability$=\frac{66}{455}+\frac{12}{455}+\frac{1}{455}+\frac{12}{455}=\frac{91}{455}=\boxed{\frac{1}{5}}$

Answer (score 0):

There are a few cases we have to consider, which are the orders that the ball are drawn. Denote $G$ and green, $B$ as blue, and $Y$ as yellow. A tuple $(a,b)$ represents that a ball of type $a$ is drawn first, followed by a ball of type $b$, and finally a green ball is drawn. The cases are as follows:

$(B,B)$: $5\cdot4\cdot3$

$(B,G)$ and $(G,B)$: $2\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2$

$(B,Y)$ and $(Y,B)$: $2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot3$

$(G,G)$: $3\cdot2\cdot1$

$(G,Y)$ and $(Y,G)$: $2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot2$

$(Y,Y)$: $7\cdot6\cdot3$

The sum of all cases is $546$. Because there are $15\cdot14\cdot13$ total ways to draw three balls, the probability is therefore:
$$\frac{546}{2730}=\boxed{\frac15}$$

Comment: I made a mistake by not considering conditional probability while calculating my third pick, there will be 9 instances of green on the final pick, all of them depending on the previous pick's outcomes and hence 9 of those outcomes will have to be multiplied (i.e GGG+BBG+BYG+YBG...and so on)

Comment: Also I don't know how you would come to the outcome to 3/15 without considering the first two pick's outcomes, I did the whole math again using conditional probability (e.g Probability of third one being green given than first 2 ta are blue...etc) and added all 9 results to come to 1/5.

Comment: @Suburban13 I think I did read the problem in the wrong way, let me calculate again.

Comment: @Suburban13 I have edited the answer, it should be correct now.

Comment: yep got my conceptual problem cleared, thanks!

Comment: @Suburban13 Each of the $15$ marbles is equally likely to be the third marble drawn.

Comment: $1/5=3/15$ @Suburban13